# Jenkins Maven integration plugin failure

Tags: java, maven, ssl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've been trying to install "maven integration" plugin in order to build a maven project and deploy it to artifactory on Jenkins and I'm failing to install the required plugins (Maven integration and Artifactory )

### **Failure details:**

```
java.security.cert.CertificateNotYetValidException: NotBefore: Mon Sep 28 10:08:51 IDT 2020
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:273)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:675)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyValidity(BasicChecker.java:190)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:144)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
Caused: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:135)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:237)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:145)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:84)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:364)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:629)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:645)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:464)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1309)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2783)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2695)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1854)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:3099)
    at java.base/java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(URLConnection.java:636)
    at java.base/java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(URLConnection.java:508)
    at java.base/java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:492)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:394)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1264)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1974)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1969)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1968)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)`enter code here`
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1280)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/maven-plugin/3.7/maven-plugin.hpi to /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin.jpi.tmp
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1287)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to download from https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/maven-plugin/3.7/maven-plugin.hpi (redirected to: https://mirror.serverion.com/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/3.7/maven-plugin.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1321)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1869)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2147)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1843)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running behind some kind of proxy / firewall? In case you are.. you would need to add those details into Jenkins. You could also download the jenkins plugin and all it's dependent plugins and upload them one by one manually. (Just too much work though!)

Comment: That's right there was proxy configured in my browser so I just turned it off and it worked! thank you